# How to count the number of times a string appears in a column in a 2D array?

Tags: c#

I need to set up a 2D array to hold the names of singers and their gender, and then count the number of males and display it on a label, and the number of females on another label. I've created the array (properly I think) but I do not know how to loop through only the 2nd column.  Here's my array:

```
string[,] singers =
{
    {"Beyonce", "F"},
    {"David Bowie", "M"},
    {"Hikaru Utada", "F"},
    {"Madonna", "F"},
    {"Elton John", "M"},
    {"Koji Tamaki", "M"}
};
```

I'm very new to C# so any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `string[,]` you can use `string[][]` and do something like

```
string[,] singers =
{
    {"Beyonce", "F"},
    {"David Bowie", "M"},
    {"Hikaru Utada", "F"},
    {"Madonna", "F"},
    {"Elton John", "M"},
    {"Koji Tamaki", "M"}
};


int females = 0, males = 0;
foreach(string[] arr in singers)
{
    if(arr[1] == "F") females++;
    else if(arr[1] == "M") males++;
}
```

In this method, you are essentially using an array of arrays to make iterating through it relatively easier. foreach loop gives each array in the two-dimensional array separately and you can check the element at index 1 to get the gender.

Or if you really have to use `string[,]`, you can do

```
string[,] singers =
{
    {"Beyonce", "F"},
    {"David Bowie", "M"},
    {"Hikaru Utada", "F"},
    {"Madonna", "F"},
    {"Elton John", "M"},
    {"Koji Tamaki", "M"}
};

int females = 0, males = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < singers.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if(singers[i, 1] == "F") females++;
    else if(singers[i, 1] == "M") males++;
}
```

`array.GetLength(int dimension)` gives the length of a particular dimension of an array. So we get the length of the first dimension, iterate through that and get the value at index 1 to access the gender values.